# How to split a large dataset into multiple Excel  spreadsheets using an SSIS package?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, excel, ssis

I'm facing a problem with an SSIS package.

- A query is executed to obtain some data from the DataBase (SQL Server
  2008) (Data Flow Task executed)
- Export the data extracted to an Excel 97-2003 spreadsheet (.xls) using Excel Destination

As most of you know the xls files are limited per sheet to 65,536 rows by 256 columns. So when the query extracts more than the records limit (65,536), the Excel Destination Step fails.

I get the following error messages.

`Error: 0xC0202009 at Calidad VIDA, Excel Destination [82]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.`

`Error: 0xC0209029 at Calidad VIDA, Excel Destination [82]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "input "Excel Destination Input" (93)" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "input "Excel Destination Input" (93)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure. Error: 0xC0047022 at Calidad VIDA, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. The ProcessInput method on component "Excel Destination" (82) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Excel Destination Input" (93). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.`

`Error: 0xC02020C4 at Calidad VIDA, OLE DB Source [1]: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.`

`Error: 0xC0047038 at Calidad VIDA, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED. The PrimeOutput method on component "OLE DB Source" (1) returned error code 0xC02020C4. The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.`

The file needs to be in that format, because the clients don't have newer versions. And they don't want to buy licenses. Does anyone know how to work around with this issue?
I should use a Script task and make the excel by my own, or I should make a for each loop and create various excels woorkbooks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one possible option that you can use to create Excel worksheets dynamically using the SSIS based on how many number of records you want to write per Excel sheet. This doesn't involve Script tasks. Following example describes how this can be achieved using Execute SQL Tasks, For Loop container and Data Flow Task. The example was created using `SSIS 2008 R2`.

**Step-by-step process:**

1. In SQL Server database, run the scripts provided under **SQL Scripts** section. These scripts will create a table named `dbo.SQLData` and then will populate the table with multiplication data from `1 x 1` through `20 x 40`, thereby creating **800** records. The script also creates a stored procedure named `dbo.FetchData` which will be used in the SSIS package.
2. On the SSIS package, create **9** variables as shown in screenshot #**1**. Following steps describe how each of these variables are configured.
3. Set the variable **ExcelSheetMaxRows** with value **80**. This variable represents the number of rows to write per Excel sheet. You can set it to value of your choice. In your case, this would be **65,535** (you might want to leave 1 row for header column names).
4. Set the variable **SQLFetchTotalRows** with value `SELECT COUNT(Id) AS TotalRows FROM dbo.SQLData`. This variable contains the query to fetch the total row count from the table.
5. Select the variable **StartIndex** and choose Properties by pressing *F4*. Set the property *EvaluateAsExpression* to `True` and the property *Expression* to the value `(@[User::Loop] *  @[User::ExcelSheetMaxRows]) + 1`. Refer screenshot #**2**.
6. Select the variable **EndIndex** and choose Properties by pressing *F4*. Set the property *EvaluateAsExpression* to `True` and the property *Expression* to the value `(@[User::Loop] + 1) *  @[User::ExcelSheetMaxRows]`. Refer screenshot #**3**.
7. Select the variable **ExcelSheetName** and choose Properties by pressing *F4*. Set the property *EvaluateAsExpression* to `True` and the property *Expression* to the value `"Sheet" + (DT_WSTR,12) (@[User::Loop] + 1)`. Refer screenshot #**4**.
8. Select the variable **SQLFetchData** and choose Properties by pressing *F4*. Set the property *EvaluateAsExpression* to `True` and the property *Expression* to the value `"EXEC dbo.FetchData " +  (DT_WSTR, 15) @[User::StartIndex] + "," +  (DT_WSTR, 15) @[User::EndIndex]`. Refer screenshot #**5**.
9. Select the variable **ExcelTable** and choose Properties by pressing *F4*. Set the property *EvaluateAsExpression* to `True` and the property *Expression* to the value provided under **ExcelTable Variable Value** section. Refer screenshot #**6**.
10. On the SSIS package's Control Flow tab, place an Execute SQL Task and configure it as shown in screenshots #**7** and #**8**. This task will fetch the record count.
11. On the SSIS package's Control Flow tab, place a For Loop Container and configure it as shown in screenshot #**9**. Please note this is **For Loop** and not Foreach Loop. This loop will execute based on the number of records to display in each Excel sheet in conjunction with the total number of records found in the table.
12. Create an Excel spreadsheet of Excel 97-2003 format containing .xls extension as shown in screenshot #**10**. I created the file in **C:\temp**
13. On the SSIS package's connection manager, create an OLE DB connection named `SQLServer` pointing to SQL Server and an Excel connection named `Excel` pointing to the newly created Excel file.
14. Click on the Excel connection and select Properties. Changes the property DelayValidation from False to True so that when we switch to using variable for sheet creation in Data Flow Task, we won't get any error messages. Refer screenshot #**11**.
15. Inside the For Loop container, place an Execute SQL Task and configure it as shown in screenshot #**12**. This task will create Excel worksheets based on the requirements.
16. Inside the For Loop container, place a Data flow task. Once the tasks are configured, the Control Flow tab should look like as shown in screenshot #**13**.
17. Inside the Data Flow Task, place an OLE DB Source to read data from SQL Server using the stored procedure. Configure the OLE DB Source as shown in screenshots #**14** and #**15**.
18. Inside the Data Flow Task, place an Excel Destination to insert the data into the Excel sheets. Configure the Excel destination as shown in screenshots #**16** and #**17**.
19. Once the Data Flow Task is configured, it should look like as shown in screenshot #**18**.
20. Delete the Excel file that was created in step **12** because the package will automatically create the file when executed. If not deleted, the package will throw the exception that Sheet1 already exists. This example uses the path C:\temp\ and screenshot #**19** shows there are no files in that path.
21. Screenshots #**20** and #**21** show the package execution inside Control Flow and Data Flow tasks.
22. Screenshot #**22** shows that file `ExcelData.xls` has been created in the path C:\temp. Remember, earlier this path was empty. Since we had 800 rows in the table and we set the package variable **ExcelSheetMaxRows** to create 80 rows per sheet. Hence, the Excel file has 10 sheets. Refer screenshot #**23**.
23. **`NOTE:`** One thing that I haven't done in this example is to check if the file ExcelData.xls already exists in the path C:\temp. If it exists, then the file should be deleted before executing the tasks. This can be achieved by creating a variable that holds the Excel file path and use a File System Task to delete the file before the first Execute SQL Task is executed.

Hope that helps.

**ExcelTable Variable Value:**

```
"CREATE TABLE `" + @[User::ExcelSheetName] + "`(`Id` Long, `Number1` Long, `Number2` Long, `Value` Long)"
```

**SQL Scripts:**

```
--Create table

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SQLData](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Number1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Number2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Multiplication] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--Populate table with data

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @OuterLoop INT
DECLARE @InnerLoop INT
SELECT @OuterLoop = 1

WHILE @OuterLoop <= 20 BEGIN

    SELECT @InnerLoop = 1   
    WHILE @InnerLoop <= 40 BEGIN

            INSERT INTO dbo.SQLData (Number1, Number2, Value)
            VALUES (@OuterLoop, @InnerLoop, @OuterLoop * @InnerLoop)

            SET @InnerLoop = @InnerLoop + 1
    END

    SET @OuterLoop = @OuterLoop + 1
END

SET NOCOUNT OFF

--Create stored procedure

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FetchData]
(
        @StartIndex INT
    ,   @EndIndex   INT
)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT  Id
        ,   Number1
        ,   Number2
        ,   Value
    FROM    (
                SELECT  RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS RowNumber
                    ,   Id
                    ,   Number1
                    ,   Number2
                    ,   Value 
                FROM    dbo.SQLData
            ) T1
    WHERE   RowNumber BETWEEN @StartIndex AND @EndIndex
END
GO
```

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

**Screenshot #7:**

[image: 7]

**Screenshot #8:**

[image: 8]

**Screenshot #9:**

[image: 9]

**Screenshot #10:**

[image: 10]

**Screenshot #11:**

[image: 11]

**Screenshot #12:**

[image: 12]

**Screenshot #13:**

[image: 13]

**Screenshot #14:**

[image: 14]

**Screenshot #15:**

[image: 15]

**Screenshot #16:**

[image: 16]

**Screenshot #17:**

[image: 17]

**Screenshot #18:**

[image: 18]

**Screenshot #19:**

[image: 19]

**Screenshot #20:**

[image: 20]

**Screenshot #21:**

[image: 21]

**Screenshot #22:**

[image: 22]

**Screenshot #23:**

[image: 23]

Answer (score 2):

The stock excel rendering option allows for options to paginate onto separate tabs.  If you force page breaks after the appropriate number of rows, you get a new tab for each "page" in your output.  I don't have the settings I have used in the past for this, but I can look it up tomorrow if you need me to.

Comment: Thanks, it would be very helpful. I can wait for tomorrow for this. I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: "In your table, try creating a group (outside of any current grouping you have) with no header or footer, and the page break after value set to true. For the grouping value, use an expression similar to 

=ROWNUMBER(Nothing) MOD 60000

This should force a page break after 60000 rows of data, which will translate into a new excel tab when you export. I believe the 65K limit in Excel is on a per worksheet basis. "

Comment: The above quote is from the following location: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic632795-1063-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Also worked for me was to use the SSIS package to export to a CSV file and then manually import the data into Excel. Note that this is not the same as "Open" in Excel, because that will also just stop at 65536 rows. Create a new xlsx file and click on "Data" -> "From Text". It will import and show all rows. Tested with 750,000 rows.

However, not sure if the csv -> xlsx conversion is easily scripted within an SSIS package. Most likely via a Script task using the Excel COM object.